# Subscriber Lists: Best Practices for multiple environments

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, fuel

Is there a best practice or a guideline on how to set up subscriber lists in our ET instance to support API integration with multiple environments?

We have multiple environments (prod, stage / dev) sending transactional email through the Fuel REST API. Stage / Dev exist for testing purposes and will have significantly less sending volume to a smaller set of mostly test accounts.  Would you typically have a subscriber list for each environment, or share the production list with the dev/stage accounts?

Thank you
-greg

Answer (score 0):

There is no sandbox/staging/development environment structure in SFMC.  If you have a grandfathered Enterprise 2.0 account and can create new Business Units without additional fees.  In that case,  you can create additional BUs for your each environment.  I've done it, but I'm not sure I would recommend it.

I think you'll find the SFMC doesn't fit with a traditional development environment unless you build a SFMC API-based application outside of the platform and just use SFMC for sending.

As for Subscribers and Lists, I'd suggest using gmail.com or outlook.com plus-addressing for testing.

Keep in mind that all E2.0 subscribers are created at the parent level and shared with all business units. Subscribers are added to All Subscribers at first email send.  Business unit Subscriber status (active, unsubscribed, bounced, held) is frustratingly difficult to determine programatically.

Comment: Thank you!  So you are saying we should just go ahead and use the 'production' triggered email setup in ET for our test accounts as well?